# Are the Standard Quantum Groups Coordinate Rings Noetherian?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

Are the standard quantum groups $C_q[G]$ Noetherian and if so what is a standard reference?

Comment: When $q$ is a non-zero, non root of unity, the answer is yes: see Chapter I.8 in Brown and Goodearl, Lectures on Algebraic Quantum Groups. I'm not sure about the root of unity case.